# Group Function not working on Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join, group-by

I'm practicing functions on Oracle SQL, and now I'm trying to code a group function to print on console AVG salary group by departments id, and I want to add the column department name from another table. I think my syntax is correct but anyway I received an Oracle Error.

```
SELECT   e.department_id, d.department_name, e.AVG(salary)
FROM     employees e
JOIN     departments d
ON      (e.department_id = d.department_id)
GROUP BY department_id, department_name;
```

> ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
>   00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action: Error en la línea: 5, columna: 10

Comment: "*I think my syntax is correct but anyway I received an Oracle Error*" - if you get an error, then your syntax is not correct.

Comment: hahaah ok I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qualify all your columns with respective alias. Also, `e.` will not be applied on `avg` function but the column salary

```
SELECT   e.department_id, d.department_name, AVG(e.salary)
FROM     employees e
JOIN     departments d
ON      (e.department_id = d.department_id)
GROUP BY e.department_id, d.department_name;
```

Comment: I've tried to do like you has suggested me but I received a new error.

Comment: @GurV - select `e.department_id` will not work when you group by `d.department_id`. You need to be consistent.

Comment: SELECT   e.AVG(salary), d.department_id, d.department_name
FROM     employees e
JOIN     departments d
ON      (e.department_id = d.department_id)
GROUP BY d.department_id, d.department_name;

Comment: Use `AVG(e.salary)` instead of `e.AVG(salary)`. Read my answer.

Comment: I've tried to do all the possibles, I just think not working because Just not working group functions with join sentence.

Comment: Sorry I didn't paid attention to first line of your code. YOur answer is right. Thanks alot for your help.